# GitHub Isuue on Visual Studio Code editor

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Can we use Git on Vs code without installing Git to the PC?

I saw couple of videos that they use git without installing VS code, need to clarify

Comment: I believe I answered your question with the information you are seeking. Once you have your Git client installed, you can configure it to connect to any remote repository that you wish, including those hosted by GitHub and GitLab. Therefore, I think we should change the title and tags here. The question is about your local Git client and VSCode, and appears to be unrelated to GitHub and GitLab. If you agree with this, I suggest removing all tags except "git" and adding the tag "visual-studio-code". And, perhaps the question title could be the same as your first sentence.

Comment: @TTT: I did that to the tags before I even read your comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is standalone software that you must [install separately](https://git-scm.com/downloads). Once installed, Visual Studio Code, like many other tools, can integrate with Git.

You can certainly use Git without installing VSCode, and you can also use VSCode without installing Git for non-Git related functionality, but you must install both Git and VSCode if you wish to use Git features inside of VSCode.

Note the [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview) regarding the integrated Git features:

> **Make sure Git is installed.** VS Code will use your machine's Git installation (at least version 2.0.0), so you need to [install Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) first before you get these features.